# scaffold-dbcontext basepath exception on EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I kept getting the following exception when I scaffold the entity framework core.  I googled and tried multiple suggestions to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017.  I have installed the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`,
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design` and
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` packages via NuGet

**This is the exception:**

> Exception calling "AddFromFile" with "1" argument(s):
>     "'basePath' cannot be an empty string ("") or start with the null character.
>     Parameter name: basePath"

**These are the commands I have tried:**

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=1234;UserId=2345;password=3456;Database=4567;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force

Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=1234;Initial Catalog=4567;User ID=2345;Password=3456" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -force -v

Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Data Source=1234;UserId=2345;password=3456;Database=4567;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to Scaffold a database with the `-OutputDir` value set to a directory that didn't exist. I was hoping it would create the directory but it doesn't. Just make sure your output directory exists and you shouldn't see this error.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by removing the folder dotnet in `C\Program Files (x86)`.
It's probably using this in reference for dotnet commands when I believe it should be using the x64 one (`C\Program Files\dotnet`).
Give it a shot.